# How to whitelist GitHub Action IPs in windows server firewall

Tags: windows, github, github-actions, windows-firewall

I have windows server 2012. I did setup gitlab CI/CD to automatically build and upload build to server. I do copy files with [appleboy/scp-action@master](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action) GitHub Action. It works! I do have username/key authentication and would like to add windows firewall rules for ssh.

Is this possible to make firewall inbound rule for all IPs of GitHub Actions. If I understand correctly, they are all listed in [here](https://api.github.com/meta).

Comment: IIUC, that Windows Server 2012 is deployed somewhere with a public IP, and you want to whitelist all the GitHub Actions IPs (**3308** in total, as of now) beforehand to allow deployments from any of GHA's runners having those public IPs, right? And, that is in addition to existing SSH authentication mechanisms? What is the purpose of this exactly? That would also include some cron job (scheduled task in Windows) to check https://api.github.com/meta periodically to update (add/delete) firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly, SSH authentication mechanism is present. With whitelisting of IP`s I want to add one more protection layer. You are correct about scheduled task in windows to update IPs. That would be the most persistent solution.

Comment: Right. Wouldn't it, i.e. whitelisting all the IPs at once, be akin to making that machine susceptible to [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#:~:text=A%20distributed%20denial%2Dof%2Dservice%20(DDoS)%20attack%20occurs,of%20hosts%20infected%20with%20malware.) attacks or that part is already taken care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you actually need to do that (for *all* IPs listed at https://api.github.com/meta), but if you do, that would be a powershell script (surely run as admin) with:

```
$ips = @()
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.github.com/meta
$ips += $response.actions
Get-NetFirewallrule -DisplayName 'WEB-Inbound'|Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress $ips
```

Add in `$ips` the JSON section you need from meta ('web', 'packages', 'pages', ...)

Comment: For GitHub Actions $response.actions are the correct IPs.